# Bash: как записать вывод команды из HEREDOC в лог файл

Tags: linux, bash

Есть основной сервер. Он выполняет большой список команд с помощью HEREDOC по SSH на удалённом сервере. К каждой команде есть условие if. Результат выполнения команд на удалённом сервере логируется в файл на основном сервере. Но проблема в том, что логирование работает очень криво. Либо не работает в принципе, либо если завернуть в функцию, то выполняется всегда в независимости от результата. Как это можно реализовать? Либо можно реализовать подобный скрипт без HEREDOC?

Пример:

```
function ssh_connection {
      ssh -T -i <ssh_key> root@10.20.30.40
}
log="Failed! $(date)"
log_file=/var/log/log_file
ssh_connection << SCRIPT
          command
          if [ \$? - eq 0 ]
          then
                 echo "Success"
          else
                 echo "Failed"
                 echo $log >> $log_file
          fi
SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой пример
Поставил комментарии по набору команд
`EOF>>${log_file}` - будет перенаправлять вывод с удаленной машины в указанный внутри переменной файл.

```
#Лог файл
log_file=/var/log/log_file

#Функция для подстановки временной метки сообщению
say() {
    echo "`date +'%Y-%m-%d %T'` --> ${1}"
}

#Функция для запуска простых команд с проверкой выхода
#Первый аргумент команда, второй комментарий для логирования
runner() {
    #Запуск с переводом в поток ошибок, что бы вывод команды не попал в лог файл
    ${1} 1>&2
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        say "FAIL: ${2}"
    else
        say "OK: ${2}"
    fi
}

#Подключаемся на удаленную машину, отключаем приветствие
ssh -T -i <ssh_key> root@10.20.30.40 '/bin/bash --norc' <<EOF>>${log_file}
    #Устанавливаем функции для удаленной машины, так как до этого момента они были объявлены только локально
    $(typeset -f say)
    $(typeset -f runner)
    #Логируем начало работы для хоста
    say "INFO - запущен скрипт - `hostname`"
    runner "true" 'правда'
    runner "false" "псевдоправла"
    say "INFO - завершено выполнение"
EOF
```